# How to use property file in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-webdriver

```
     //Reading data from property file :

      String username = prop.getProperty("username");
      String password = prop.getProperty("password");
           @Test
public void testValidCredentials()  {
obj.loginAs("username","password");
```

}

public HomePage loginAs(String username, String password) {

```
    driver.findElement(By.id("id1")).sendKeys(username);
    driver.findElement(By.id("id2")).sendKeys(password);
    driver.findElement(By.id("id3")).click();
    return new HomePage(driver);
```

}

**What i was trying to do is pass username and password to loginAs method but however when i pass it inserts as Email as Username and password as password instead of what i read from my property file.** 
**Property file** :
username = r@t.com
password = 1234

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem might be in this line

```
obj.loginAs("username","password");
```

change it to

```
obj.loginAs(username,password);
```

that is username, password without quotes.

Comment: +1. In its current stage, OP is passing "username" and "password", two string literals, not the desired ``username`` and ``password`` string variables.